# ZSH Shell: Executable alias from function parameter

Tags: linux, shell, parameter-passing, zsh, alias

i tried to execute an alias which is given via parameters on a function. But i can't execute the alias. I also can't find a solution for it. Anyone have an idea for this case?

This works:

```bash
alias rabbitmq='cd xy/_infra/v2/rabbitmq'

test () {
    echo "run alias"
    rabbitmq
}
```

This won't work:

```bash
alias rabbitmq='cd xy/_infra/v2/rabbitmq'

runAlias () {
    local aliasCmd=$1

    echo "run alias $aliasCmd"
    $aliasCmd
}

test () {
    runAlias rabbitmq
}
```

Output is this:

```
run alias rabbitmq
runAlias:4: command not found: rabbitmq
```

I tried to use this with quotes, brackets and with the function `${BASH_ALIASES[$alias_key]}`, but nothing helped.

I would like to execute the alias which is given by parameter to a function.

Comment: I don't see how `BASH_ALIASES` could be of any relevance here, when you don't run bash.  For debugging, do a `type $aliasCmd` inside your function.

Comment: @user1934428 it looks correct for me:
`rabbitmq is an alias for cd xy/_infra/v2/rabbitmq`

Comment: I'm not a Zsh person, but the general guidance would be to avoid aliases.

Comment: @tripleee : Same for me, but if the OP wants to use them, I think it's up to him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alias-expansion is done before parameter expansion. If you really **want** the alias to be understand, you would have to do

```
eval "$aliasCmd"
```

But I would rather recommend a redesign of your code so that you don't need an alias to be passed to a function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems to helped me.

Why i use aliases: i need it for manual "shortcut" and also in functions. So i will not have duplicated paths in this case to prevent multiple changes. But yesterday i think about your answer and have the idea to use a variable - which i can use in alias and in function. So my requirements could be completely covered.

I think i would use variables instead of the eval - but for now `eval` is a good solution till i can globally change the logic.
 
Thank you a lot!

Comment: @devKyrios: Just being curious: Is there a reason why you model your shortcuts with an `alias` and not with a `function`? To be honest, I have never found a reasonable use for an `alias` in a script, and I use an `alias` over a function mostly for defining a shortcut on the commandline, because the definition of an alias requires less typing than that of a function.